# How to automatic add a new line with left hand or after paste with atom editor?

Tags: newline, enter, atom-editor

I'm selecting a lot of text with a mouse and pasting it at atom editor. So I select text with mouse (**right hand**), copy it (crlt+c, **left hand**), paste it (ctrl+v, **left hand**), and hit enter (**right hand**);

I don't want to let go of my **right hand** to hit enter. I would like to after paste, add a new line automatically ou just add a new line with my left hand.

I tried adding CTRL-D as a new line, but it conflicts with other keybinding.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new keybinding for it.

Open the Settings view (`Packages > Settings View > Open`), and open your `keymap.cson` file from the Keybindings menu.

Paste the following at the bottom of the `keymap.cson` file.

```
'atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
  'ctrl-shift-a': 'editor:newline'
```

This assigns the <kbd>ctrl-shift-a</kbd> keyboard shortcut to the `newline` action.

I chose this specific keybinding because it can be easily typed with your left-hand, and it doesn't conflict with any other keybindings. However, you can change it to anything you like.

---

**Note:** I am assuming that your are on a Windows/Linux system. Please let me know otherwise so I can edit the answer.